# Grafana/Influx Db Authentication to data source failed

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am trying to integrate grafana and influxdb to get some metrics. But not sure when I am trying to test it, authentication to data source is failing. Please help me out with this issue.

Here is the below yaml and conf file.

Docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - grafana-volume:/vol01/Docker/monitoring
    environment:
      - GF_LOG_LEVEL=debug
      - GF_DATAPROXY_LOGGING=true
      - GF_DATAPROXY_TIMEOUT=60

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    container_name: influxdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - influxdb-volume:/vol01/Docker/monitoring
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=telegraf
      - INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED=false
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=Welcome1
      - GF_LOG_LEVEL=debug
      - GF_DATAPROXY_LOGGING=true

  telegraf:
    image: telegraf
    container_name: telegraf
    restart: always
    extra_hosts:
     - "influxdb:18.216.224.127"
    environment:
      ST_PROC: /rootfs/proc
      HOST_SYS: /rootfs/sys
      HOST_ETC: /rootfs/etc


    volumes:
     - ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
     - /sys:/rootfs/sys:ro
     - /proc:/rootfs/proc:ro
     - /etc:/rootfs/etc:ro
networks:
  monitoring:
volumes:
  grafana-volume:
```

Conf file

```
[global_tags]

[agent]
  interval = "60s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  hostname = "18.216.224.127"
  omit_hostname = false

[[outputs.influxdb]]
urls = ["http://18.216.224.127:8086"]
database = "telegraf"
timeout = "5s"
username = "telegraf"
password = "Welcome1"


[[inputs.ping]]
interval = "5s"
urls = ["192.168.0.44", "192.168.0.131", "192.168.0.130", "google.com", "amazon.com", "github.com"]
count = 4
ping_interval = 1.0
timeout = 2.0


[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = true
  totalcpu = true
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false


[[inputs.disk]]
  ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs", "iso9660", "overlay", "aufs", "squashfs"]

[[inputs.diskio]]

[[inputs.kernel]]

[[inputs.mem]]

[[inputs.processes]]

[[inputs.swap]]

[[inputs.system]]
```

ERROR

t=2021-05-08T11:02:29+0000 lvl=info msg="Authentication to data source failed" logger=data-proxy-log userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/query remote_addr=108.237.178.97 referer=http://18.216.224.127:3000/datasources/edit/1/ body="{"code":"unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized"}" statusCode=401
t=2

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue when using InfluxQL language. Using Flux fixed the problem. Since the latest influxdb images - 2.x, use a slightly different set of envvars, you'll have to change them. According to https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/influxdb/README.md#automated-setup, you need to change existing envvars to:

- DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME
- DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD
- DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG
- etc

And also to use Flux you have to add DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN envvar. Here is an example of docker-compose part of the "influxdb" service:

```
environment:
  - INFLUXDB_DB=telegraf
  - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
  - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=admin
  - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=Welcome1
  - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=telegraf_org
  - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=telegraf_bucket
  - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=admin_token
```

In the Grafana UI:

- change InfluxQL to Flux
- put *_ORG, *_BUCKET, and *_ADMIN_TOKEN envvars values into according inputs of "InfluxDB Details" section

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Grafana UI set up, you can test this from your browser at /datasources. Here you can find your data source. If you click "Save & test" it will tell you whether it was able to find buckets. If it can't, you may have wrong url, credentials or auth settings configured.

For me, the problem was that after I reset my influxdb deployment, credentials had changed and I needed to update this in the datasource config. This method allowed me to quickly check my configuration before committing any configuration (I use helm).